# Where to save a xindy style?

Tags: paths, xindy

What is the best place to save a xindy style file (`.xdy`)? I read about `XINDY_SEARCHPATH` but what if I can’t change it because I’m only the developer and have no access to the users settings or when I want to publish a style via CTAN. Is there any place for such files?

Furthermore the file should not be deleted if the distribution is updated.

Comment: xindy doesn't use kpathsea (yet?). And the search pathes are quite hard coded. (I also have doubts that `XINDY_SEARCHPATH` works as advertised in the code but didn't test it.) Imho if you want to publish a style you should ask the xindy maintainer to include it in the xindy package itself.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Hm … thanks for this comment. If you post it as answer I’ll accept it. The actual style is for a client and not for CTAN but I hoped for some TDS-like advices to prevent explaining how to install the style manually to my client …

Comment: I posted a [feature request on SF](https://sourceforge.net/p/xindy/feature-requests/45/) but I don’t know how active the developer is at the moment. His last activity was 2 months ago …