# What is the best (most robust) way to install a custom Xindy style?

Tags: miktex, texlive, xindy

I’m developing a (non-public) custom class which has a comparing Xindy style file (`.xdy`). I’m installing the class feels etc. according to TDS with a script (or by unzipping to the right directories). But I couldn’t figure out a robust way to install the Xindy file, since it doesn’t use `kpsewhich`. **So what is the best place to save such a style?** It should

- work with TeX Live and MikTeX
- be as easy as possible
- ideally not requiring to change `.profile` or something like that

I don’t know what systems the users have. But I guess most of them are basic users without any knowledge about installing packages or using the Terminal/Bash/…

Deployment via CTAN is not possible since the class/style is exclusive and non-public.

Comment: Easiest is always going to be 'here', as in 'in the current working directory'. MiKTeX doesn't register a user tree as standard so for those users you will have to have some minimal instructions if you want to support system installations.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention the “same directory” method, which would work but a “real“ installation would be better :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: miktex has (two) standard user trees but  the problem is imho the "xindy don't use kpsewhich" part, if I remember correctly xindy simply doesn't look in other trees but I will have to recheck the details -- long ago that I tried.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks. Then I guess I stick to “install in project folder” as a work around. I forgot that a I asked this [question in 2014](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185197/4918) already … I voted to close the old one as duplicate of this one.

Comment: Looks like you are developing this stuff for quite a long time now...

Comment: @Matsmath: Nope … these where different projects ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it seems like the answer is **there is no way**, since Xindy doesn’t use `kpathsea`. In 2014 I posted a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/xindy/feature-requests/45/) at SourceForge and it is assigned to the 2.6 mile stone (current ist v2.3).

So th easiest way to “install” is to copy the style file in the project folder.

Comment: Perhaps there is hope: Akira did sent me a patch to add kpsewhich to xindy, I will test it and report back.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: sounds great :-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hi, are there any news on this? Is using the current version using kpsewhich?